# Adding onEventClick listener on syncfusion scheduler

Tags: angular, scheduler, syncfusion, nebular

So i have a little problem with creation such listener. Is it possible to create onEventClick listener in syncfusion scheduler?[image]

I want to call Nebular dialog by clicking on event, not by clicking on empty space in schedular.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is your question and what means 'clicking on event', but anyway you can attach click event listener pretty much on anything inside the DOM, so my answer is "Yes". 
Please provide some details on what you want to achieve and what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

We have validated your reported query “**I want to call Nebular dialog by clicking on event**” at our end. You can open your customized popup on the event click with the help of the **popupOpen** event of the Schedule like the below code. We have prepared a sample for your reference and it can be available below.

**[app.component.ts]**

```
  public onPopupOpen(args: PopupOpenEventArgs): void {
    if (args.type !== 'QuickInfo' && args.type !== 'Editor')
      return;

    if (!args.target.classList.contains('e-appointment'))
      return;

    if (args.type === 'QuickInfo') {
      // To prevent the default quick info popup by args.cancel is set to true.
      args.cancel = true;
      alert('You can use your customized popup here for quick info popup.');
    } else if (args.type === 'Editor') {
      // To prevent the default editor window popup by args.cancel is set to true.
      args.cancel = true;
      alert('You can use your customized popup here for editor popup.');
    }
  }
```

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/ej2-angular-schedule-open-custom-popup-on-event-click-fsm1jr?file=app.component.ts

Kindly try the above sample and get back to us if you would require further assistance.

**API(popupOpen event):** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/schedule/#popupopen

Regards,
Ravikumar Venkatesan